# Using Interfaces among multiple Projects ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have one project with multiple libraries.  The problem I have is that I can’t access some libraries from others, as when I add a reference I get an error about circular dependencies.  I assume I need to create an interface but I am not really sure how to structure it.  Here is an example of what I have:
My references are setup like this:

1. WebApp (This is an ASP.Net web site) - Has Reference to BusinessLayer Class Library and Utilities Class Library
2. Data Class Library (This library provides abstract database functionality) -  has no references
3. BusinessLayer Class Library (provides a business logic layer) -  has references to Data Class Library, DataLayer Class Library, and Utilities Class Library
4. DataLayer Class Library (provides a layer that directly interfaces with the database i.e. CRUD commands) - has references Data Class Library and Utilities Class Library
5. Utilities Class Library (general library that are used across all layers) -  has no references

For the most part this is fine.  But, I have a class in the Utilities Class Library that needs to reference functions and properties in the WebApp and BusinessLayer Class Libraries.  I cannot add a reference to these projects, as that would create a circular dependency.  So, how would I go about setting up the Interface and the correct references?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have designed your application is very similar to architecture pattern defined 
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture)

As for your utility class, you can define an interface in BusinessLayer/domain layer and implement that interface in utility layer. Please note it should only return types defined in business layer/domain. This way you will get a nice separation of concerns. If let's say your web needs to consume this utility method, you can apply transformation to convert your domain type into web project specific type. This way you won't run into circular dependency.

I created a sample application based on these principles, you can refer to my [github](https://github.com/dotnetphreak/ShoppingCart/tree/dev/ShoppingCart)
project.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to move those common functions out of webapp and into your utilities library. I don't think you should be referencing your web app from any of your other libraries.